# handling browser back button in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have just started angularJs in my application. In my index.html page, I have a table with links and a sidebar which will be shown by default. When we click the link, it goes to the summary screen where I hide the sidebar. I have a link in the summary screen which routes back to the index page where I show the sidebar again.

Now the issue is, when the user clicks the link on the summary page, the sidebar is shown on the index page, but if the user clicks the back button on the browser, the sidebar does not show up..

I am using angular ng-show to show.hide the sidebar. Why does the ng-show tag does not get updated based on the browser back button but does not get activated for link on the summary screen?

The code snippet in the summary screen is shown below:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Details</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The code snippet in the details page is shown below:

```
        <div class="row" ng-controller="StateCtrl">
           <div>
               <div data-ng-view=""></div>
           </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3" ng-show="sidebar.show" id="sidebar" ng-controller="sidebarController">
                <hr/>
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">States</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <h4>States</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" ng-options="state.name for state in states" ng-model="state">
                             </select>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Please let me know how to handle the browser back button scenario.

Comment: could you  paste  code  what  you have done.

Comment: Added the code snippet for reference..

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the $rootScope and setting the value inside the two controllers. in the default controller the value will be set to true and in case the sidebar should not be shown I am setting the value to false.